# Connect router to a fiber optic modem

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I have a modem with optical fiber technology with WI-FI. Straight cable connection with two PC is stable and fast (around 450 **M**bits/sec), but every WI-FI driven connection is extremely slow and unstable (compare to cable connection WI-FI is only ~35 **M**bits/sec).

I was told that if i plug router with 5**G*H*z WI-FI capability to the main modem i can have at least 100 **M**bits/sec on all my WI-FI devices, such as smartphones, **TV**, apple MacBook.

Is that possible? I don`t want to spend extra money for another device if its not true.

I need to be clear. I need to know, if i plug ANOTHER router with 5**GH**z in existing one, does it improve my wifi connection?

Comment: ... all the milli and gigi bit thingies removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is simplistic - there is some truth in the statement, but it promises more then it delivers.

Telco provided routers (and your telco modem is actually a router) are often made to a low pricepoint and bad WIFI is a common complaint.

One of many ways to improve performance is to get a router which supports 5g - 5g WIFI performs way better then 2.4 gig WIFI, but has a smaller range.  Tour devices do need to support 5g, but its pretty well established, so if your equipment is of OK spec and not ancient it will likely work.

There are also vast differences between cheaply made routers and good ones - everything from more and more sensitive transmitters/receivers to more antennas to better software can all make a huge difference.

There are also different WIFI standards - a 35 megabit connection on an old standard connection is actually pretty good.

One thing to be aware of is that depending on your setup you may need to reconfigure your router so it uses a different IP range.  (Unless you are able to simply replace your telco one with a new one - but we dont have enough info to be sure)

Comment: I have ECI B-FOCuS 0-4G2PW router. It's provided me by my isp. As far as I know router itself cannot share wifi at 5ghz. So, if I connect 5ghz router to it I can have faster wifi?

Comment: 5GHz, and 5G are two different things - the above doesn't make a clear distinction. 5G is a mobile / cell phone tech slowly being adopted locally here (where I live), slowly becoming an option to 4G / LTE. 5GHz WiFi is in your WiFi Access point.

Comment: There is not a lot of Englush info on that device, but from the specs Ive seen that WIFI is very low end - you should be able to get much better WIFI if you get an AC (or better) capable router/AP of decent quality.   If you get a router you will need to change it away from 192.168.1.x (eg maybe use 10.0.0.x) for it to work.  An AP might be easier to configure.